# How to put nconf property inside a Javascript object

Tags: node.js, nconf

I am loading `config.json` file using `nconf` like below:

```
nconf.file({ file: '../config.json' });
```

. I am using a property in that config file which I can print on console and it works:

```
console.log('mailhost: '+ nconf.get('mailhost'));
```

But my requirement is to have an object where I can dynamically put nconf properties like so:

```
var mailConfig = {
    "mailhost": nconf.get('mailhost')
};
console.log('mailConfig: '+ JSON.stringify(mailConfig));
```

The above doesn't work as it prints empty object on console.

However, if I happen to load the config.json file using node like so:

```
var config = require('../config.json');
```

And use it to do exact same I did with nconf then it works well:

```
    var mailConfig = {
    "mailhost": config.mailhost
};
console.log('mailConfig: '+ JSON.stringify(mailConfig));
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You appear to have a typo with capitalization in the argument to `.get()` -- `mailHost` in the 1st (upper `H`) vs. `mailhost` in the 2nd (lower `h`).

Comment: Side note: `console.log()` will format an object, listing its keys and values, if it's provided as a separate argument -- `console.log('mainConfig:', mailConfig);`. Using this would have likely shown you `mainConfig: { mailhost: undefined }`.

Comment: my mistake while typing in stackoverflow. I corrected it. This typo issue is not there in actual code.